# Расстояние между существительным и словом «который»

Tags: грамматика, стилистика

В таком предложении:

> Левой рукой она придерживала тонкий ремешок сумочки со стразами, которая всё время болталась на боку и стремилась свалиться с плеча.

Вопрос про расстояние между «сумочкой» и «которая». В идеале оно должно быть минимальным. Тут желательно без «со стразами»? Где предел этому расстоянию? Какое есть правило на эту тему?
Спасибо.

Comment: Не вполне понимаю, почему желательно без «со стразами». Это ведь очень короткая цепочка из одного слова (с предлого), зависимого от «сумочки». Я поискал по корпусу, это достаточно типичная ситуация, когда описывающие предмет слова действительно должны быть после существительного, и больше их поставить некуда.

Comment: "Левой рукой она придерживала тонкий ремешок украшенной стразами сумочки, которая всё время болталась на боку и стремилась свалиться с плеча." 
Так лучше видна связь между распространяющим предложением и словом, которое оно распространяет?

Comment: "украшенной стразами сумочки" - ваш вариант мне больше всего понравился. Если бы это был ответ, я бы выбрал его, как лучший.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Ведро с картошкой, которое стояло с сенях". По-моему, ничего страшного.

Тэг "грамматика" тут вряд ли годится. Скорее, "стилистика", которая, пожалуй, почти не формализуется. Всё на слух и на вкус.

Вариант:

*Левой рукой она придерживала сумочку. Сумочка была утыкана стразами и болталась на боку, тонкий ремешок норовил соскользнуть с плеча.*

Answer (score 4):

Между определяемым словом и обособление, начинающимся словом "который" допускаются слова, если они не в том же роде и/или числе, что и определяемое слово. Если бы вместо "страз" (множественное число) была бы, например, "застёжка", то фраза была бы неправильной, так как оборот относился к последнему слову.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему мнению, правило только одно: если возможна амфиболия, расстояние должно быть нулевое, а если амфиболии нет - любое.

Comment: As in: "Ремешок портфельчика, который болтался на боку"?

Comment: Yes. In sentences like this, the distance really matters. "Ремешок портфельчика, который болтался на боку" - though awkward, but still acceptable; "Ремешок портфельчика со стразами, который болтался на боку" - nonsense.

Comment: Why limit ambiguity ? - "Рукоятку сумки с брошью, которая болталась на боку" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: use "[активные причастия](http://www.interword.se/Syntax/Lektionsmaterial/GVOZDEV/m/stil529.htm) (прошедшего времени)":

> Левой рукой она придерживала тонкий ремешок сумочки со стразами, всё время `болтавшейся` на боку и `стремившейся` свалиться с плеча.

But, they can be considered bookish by many, and, they rarely used in International Russian.

Option 2: split up the long sentence. See [Avi Gordon's answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/8164/4817).